# Facing difficulty while using BufferedInputStream inplace of Scanner

Tags: java, stdin, java.util.scanner, stringtokenizer, bufferedinputstream

For reading input from `STDIN` i always used `Scanner` object. Recently I read about `BufferedInputStream` [here](http://www.codechef.com/wiki/java) that BufferedInputStream is fastest way to read input. In `Scanner` we have various methods (to read `integer` `nextInt()`, to read `byte nextByte()`, to read `string next()` etc.)
Currently i am reading some strings (at max 100000 characters) and some integers. According to these integers, i further run my for loop which takes input from the `STDIN`. Below is the code snippet which i use till now-

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numOfStr = sc.nextInt();
    String inputStr[] = new String[numOfStr];
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfStr; i++) {
                inputStr[i] = sc.next();
        }
    }
```

However with `BufferedInputStream` we have only `read()` to read input. So how can i differentiate among the inputs? Can somebody please write down the `BufferedInputStream` code equivalent to the above `Scanner` ? Should i use `StringTokenizer` class to tokenize to data which i am getting from `read()` ? Will this not make the whole stuff (reading input from the `STDIN`) more slower than `Scanner`?

Comment: I believe BufferedReader wraps BufferedInputStream and provides these useful methods. However, if you're reading from the keyboard, speed is of little concern, since even the fastest human input will be orders of magnitude slower than all but the crudest reader. In this case, I (personally) think the simplicity of using Scanner outweighs any imagined performance gain from using a buffered reader.

Comment: @jpm: Please do not confuse with keyboard. This can be any `STDIN` source.

Answer (score 1):

BufferedInputStream doesn't parse any of the data, it just reads in the data.  You can pass a buffered reader into the scanner class and parse it from there.

Comment: Can you please explain me in more details? I would be thankful to you if you can please write down the `BufferedInputStream` code equivalent to my `Scanner` code?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [chapter on streams](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/) in the Java tutorial. It describes the different types of streams, their purposes and usage.

However, I don't quite understand why the read operation has to be fast when reading input from the user. The user will type much slower (orders of magnitude slower) than whichever method you use to read input from the keyboard.

Comment: Please replace keyboard with any `STDIN` source. `STDIN` can be anything. [This page](http://www.codechef.com/wiki/java) promotes to use `BufferedInputStream` in place of `Scanner`.

Comment: You can edit the question and remove the word "keyboard" to make it clearer.